# String (C++) in XCode

Tags: c++, string

Does anyone know why in XCode, when you do something simple like

```
string str;
cout << "input string";
getline(cin, str);
cout << str;
```

you would get malloc: *** error for object 01x100000240: pointer being freed was not allocated error?  thanks.

Comment: This looks like a bug in XCode, I'm also getting this problem.

Answer (score 2):

It's a bug in xcode. To fix it, paste these lines at the very beginning of your program (before any #include statements):

```
#define _GLIBCXX_FULLY_DYNAMIC_STRING 1
#undef _GLIBCXX_DEBUG
#undef _GLIBCXX_DEBUG_PEDANTIC
```

Comment: Defining _GLIBCXX_FULLY_DYNAMIC_STRING=1 everywhere in my project solved it for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a bug in your implementation. You may have left out something important, try a complete test case:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>
// iostream not required to declare operator<<(ostream&,char const*)
// but ostream is
#include <string>

int main() {
  using namespace std;
  cout << "Input: ";
  string line;
  if (!getline(cin, line)) {
    clog << "Input error.\n";
    return 1;
  }
  cout << "You entered: " << line << '\n';
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a couple references to this bug in XCode via Google. The best workaround I found was

> The solution is to double-click on the
>   target to open its Info window, go to
>   the Build tab, and scroll down to the
>   "GCC 4.2 - Preprocessing" section. In
>   this section is a setting named
>   "Preprocessor Macros" that by default
>   has two entries, "_GLIBCXX_DEBUG=1"
>   and "_GLIBCXX_DEBUG_PEDANTIC=1".
>   Remove these entries.